# How to suppress error from a single line of script

Tags: bash

I'm reading in a log file checking for the log chronological sequence. I'm reading the log file into an array, only storing correctly formatted timestamp log lines:

MESSAGE_ONE is the line read from the file.

> Timestamp1=$(echo "$MESSAGE_ONE" | cut -c1-20)
>   Timestamp1date=$(date -d "$Timestamp1" +%s)  *This line produces an error for incorrectly formatted lines*

I handle the error as follows:

> if [ "$?" = "1" ]; then
>          continue
>   else
>   Add the valid log line into the array

It works the way I want it to; all I want to do is suppress the error produced by badly formatted log entries.
I've tried

> Timestamp1date=$(date -d "$Timestamp1" +%s) 2>/dev/null

but it didn't work. I don't want to suppress all errors output by using 2>/dev/null after the cli command. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirection should be inside the sub shell, so use:

```
Timestamp1date=$(date -d "$Timestamp1" '+%s' 2>/dev/null)
```